# Access Windows Server RDP instance with wrong static IP configuration

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2008-r2, static-ip

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance set up in Amazon Web Services providing DNS and Active Directory services to other Server 2008 R2 instances.

While changing the static IP address, I made a typo which means that the server is now inaccessible via RDP.

So far, I have tried to fix my mistake both via a remote connection within Server Manager, and via PSTools to execute `netsh` commands remotely. As the server is inaccessible, I have been unsuccessful.

What now?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix it.

1. Create a new network interface via the EC2 control panel
2. Detach the existing public IP address from the existing network interface
3. Attach that public IP to the new network interface
4. Detach the existing network interface from your interface
5. Attach the new network interface to your interface
6. Connect to your instance and update the static IP
7. Detach the new network interface
8. Reattach the existing network interface

Hey presto!